# Create DataSet for Multi-Series FusionCharts from table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I have data from a table:

```
var my_data = [
{"series":"group1", "type":"device1", "value":15},
{"series":"group1", "type":"device3", "value":12},
{"series":"group2", "type":"device1", "value":16},
{"series":"group2", "type":"device1", "value":11},
{"series":"group2", "type":"device2", "value":17},
{"series":"group2", "type":"device2", "value":18},
{"series":"group2", "type":"device3", "value":10},
{"series":"group2", "type":"device4", "value":14},
{"series":"group3", "type":"device1", "value":13},
{"series":"group3", "type":"device3", "value":19},
{"series":"group3", "type":"device4", "value":11},
{"series":"group3", "type":"device4", "value":15}
];
```

I'm struggling with the code to convert that into the categories and dataset required by a FusionCharts multi-series chart... The results should be:

```
var my_categories = [{"category": [{"label": "device1"}, {"label": "device2"}, {"label": "device3"}, {"label": "device4"}]}];

var my_dataset = [
{"seriesname": "group1", "data": [{"value": 15}, {"value": 0}, {"value": 12}, {"value": 0}]}, 
{"seriesname": "group2", "data": [{"value": 27}, {"value": 35}, {"value": 10}, {"value": 14}]},
{"seriesname": "group3", "data": [{"value": 13}, {"value": 0}, {"value": 19}, {"value": 26}]}
];
```

The challenges are that the dataset order must match the categories, and the data value needs to be summed to a single device per category.

How can I transform this data? I assume the first step is get the categories with a for loop. But after that, I'm stumped.

This is the working chart but with the data manually transformed:
http://jsfiddle.net/yqqbqqe9/

Comment: I would start by flattening my_data first and sum up all the values so you only have a single line for each device/groups/value set. After that, sort the new array by device, then group and iterate through it, creating the categories and data sets at the same time in a single iteration.

Comment: is the data (always) sorted by `series`?

Comment: It can be always sorted by series, I control the input from an sql table... I could also flatten before it reaches the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create some helper objects, for categories and as a reference to the same series. Then build for a new series an object with a value array with all zero values.

At least add the value to the corresponding object.

This proposal works for unsorted data, but the order of first occurence builds the order of series. This could be sorted later, if necessary.

```js
var data = [{ series: "group1", type: "device1", value: 15 }, { series: "group1", type: "device3", value: 12 }, { series: "group2", type: "device1", value: 16 }, { series: "group2", type: "device1", value: 11 }, { series: "group2", type: "device2", value: 17 }, { series: "group2", type: "device2", value: 18 }, { series: "group2", type: "device3", value: 10 }, { series: "group2", type: "device4", value: 14 }, { series: "group3", type: "device1", value: 13 }, { series: "group3", type: "device3", value: 19 }, { series: "group3", type: "device4", value: 11 }, { series: "group3", type: "device4", value: 15 }],
    categories = [{ category: [{ label: "device1" }, { label: "device2" }, { label: "device3" }, { label: "device4" }] }],
    result = data.reduce(function (categories) {
        var catIndex = categories.reduce(function (r, o, i) {
                r[o.label] = i;
                return r;
            }, {}),
            series = Object.create(null);
            
        return function (r, o) {
            if (!series[o.series]) {
                series[o.series] = {
                    seriesname: o.series,
                    data: categories.map(function () { return { value: 0 } })
                };
                r.push(series[o.series]);
            }
            series[o.series].data[catIndex[o.type]].value += o.value;
            return r;
        };
    }(categories[0].category), []);


console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks. That works and is precisely what I was looking for.